# How to export a Functional component as a redux form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-form

I am writing this code under a .tsx file. I need to convert this compoenent into a redux form and export it to its parent component. I am getting error for the following code as :-

*Line 80:3:  Argument of type 'FC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<InjectedFormProps<{}, {}, string>>'.
Type 'FunctionComponent' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<InjectedFormProps<{}, {}, string>>'.*

```
 type Props = {
  uuid?: string;
};
export const SampleProcess: React.FC<Props> = ({ uuid }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { section } = useParams();
  const forecast = useSelector(forecastSelector(uuid));
  const toReview = () => navigate(`/home/${uuid}/data`);
  const toSend = () => navigate(`/home/${uuid}/send`);
  const toTitle = () => navigate(`/home/${uuid}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((!forecast || forecast.uuid !== uuid) && uuid) {
      dispatch(ReadForecast.read(uuid));
    }
  }, [dispatch, uuid, forecast]);

  return (forecast ?
      <>
        <AccordionStyled elevation={0} square expanded={!section}>
          <AccordionSummaryStyled style={{ backgroundColor: '#aaa' }}
                                  onClick={toTitle}>
            {t('bkm.forecasts.process.basic')}
          </AccordionSummaryStyled>
          <AccordionDetailsStyled>
            <ForecastProcessBasic forecast={forecast}/>
          </AccordionDetailsStyled>
        </AccordionStyled>
        <AccordionStyled elevation={0} square
                         expanded={section === 'data'}>
          <AccordionSummaryStyled onClick={toReview}>
            {forecasts.process.data}
          </AccordionSummaryStyled>
          <AccordionDetailsStyled>
            <ForecastProcessData forecast={forecast}/>
          </AccordionDetailsStyled>
        </AccordionStyled>
        
           );
};

 export default reduxForm(
  form: 'SampleForm'
)(SampleProcess)
```